# Bitcoin confirmed but have not received anything

Tags: receiving

Transaction number 2f1271a411b296ee2fbc5941809cbf4d4718a0c564de4a437f505073a92da3b8
Why have my not received the Bitcoin

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to wait for your node to sync i.e. download 200+GB of the blockchain. I suggest making a thread on https://reddit.com/r/bitcoinbeginners and posting a link here so we can help you further. Stack exchange is not suitable for a back and forth diagnoses session.